# Genesis primary navigation and logo

Tags: css, wordpress, genesis

I am using the Genesis sample child theme. I have a couple of questions. It could be something really simple that I missed. I used the red border so I could see where the primary nav was.

The primary navigation doesn’t seem to be showing up and I have reposition the primary navigation after the header like below in the functions.php file. Does the header logo need to be a certain height for the primary navigation to show?

```
remove_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
```

Even after I increased the height of the primary navigation, it still doesn't show

And when I remove the float: left; from

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
  background: url('images/blackLogo.png') no-repeat;
  float: left;
  min-height: 117px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The header logo disappears and I have no idea why.

[Here](http://www.p-ng.com/profile/) is the link to the page.

It is meant to look like [this](http://p-ng.com/cb-header.jpg)

The logo above the navigation

Thank for any suggestions and help

Answer (score 0):

In stylesheet your genesis menu have FIXED display property and wrong height. Plesae fix this

```
.genesis-nav-menu {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* height: 1px; */
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Line 509 in stylesheet

See i have commented height 1px
and also changed, position: reltive (previously it was fixed.) Now your both menus are showing up.